# Google Sign-In server implementation returns 401

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

While trying to switch from the Google+ Sign-In in Play Services 8.1 to the new Google Sign-In in Play Services 8.3, the server side component stops working and starts throwing 401's on every API call to Google servers.

### When the Android app was using Google Play Services 8.1:

**build.gradle:**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
```

**Android client:**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .addApi(Plus.API)
         .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
         .addScope(new Scope("email"))
         .build();
String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";    
accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
        SignInActivity.this, 
        Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), 
        scopes); // then send accessToken to the server
```

**Server side:**

```
 // get user details from Google+ REST API
 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
 Plus plusService = new Plus.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null)
         .setApplicationName("AppName")
         .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
         .build();
 Person person = plusService.people().get("me").execute();
```

### When switching to Google Play Services 8.3:

**build.gradle:**

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
```

**Android app:**

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestServerAuthCode("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID", false)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
         .build();
```

With the same server code, the get("me") call returns:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

Comment: If you add `.requestScopes(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE, new Scope("email"))` to your `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder`, what does [GoogleSignInAccount.getGrantedScopes()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getGrantedScopes()) return?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read, profile, email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read, openid, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read

Comment: For your 8.3 code, could you elaborate a little bit how did you get the access token? Did you pass the `GoogleSignInAccount.getServerAuthCode()` to your server and exchanged for access token there?

Comment: No, the server side code is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, note that, with the new Google Sign-In Api, as long as basic profile scopes are requested on Android client, you can get an ID token back when exchanging the code for token on your server. If all you are looking for is full name, email address, and a picture, that should be more than enough.

You'd pass the result from [GoogleSignInAccount.getServerAuthCode()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getServerAuthCode()) to your server, then use code such as:

```
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

try {
  // Exchanges the code for tokens.
  GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
      transport,
      jsonFactory,
      // Very important: Explicitly specify this new endpoint.
      "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
      SERVER_CLIENT_ID,
      SERVER_CLIENT_SECRET,
      serverAuthCodeFromAndroid,
      "" /* redirectUri, must be blank with auth code coming from Android */)
    .execute();

  // Get the id token from the exchange result
  // It will be non-null if basic profile scopes are requested 
  // when requesting the serverAuthCode on (Android) client side.
  GoogleIdToken googleIdToken = response.parseIdToken();

  // Verify the id token
  GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier =
          new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
              // For some old version of libraries
              .setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com")
              .setAudience(Arrays.asList(SERVER_CLIENT_ID))
              .build();
  boolean verified = googleIdToken.verify(verifier);
  if (!verified) {
    // Spoofing!! This is not a legitimate id token issued by 
    // Google to your web application!
    return;
  }

  // Get the profile info.
  GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = googleIdToken.getPayload();
  String userId = payload.getSubject();
  String email = payload.getEmail();
  boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
  String name = (String) payload.get("name");
  String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
  String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
  String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
  String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
} catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
  // error handling
}
```

No Google+ API required!

Comment: But, like I previously stated in the G+ thread, this server side code variant doesn't use the G+ API (you said it yourself now), thus requiring to provide both sign in options on the server side, until all users upgrade their Android app to the latest one, that allows Google Sign-In. I guess my initial question would be if I could still use the Google+ API on the server side unchanged, but switch the Android side to the new system. Also, if I wanted to use G+ API on the server though, how would that work out? What accessToken or whatnot should be sent from the client side?

Comment: Just tested the above server code. It works with the new Google Sign-In system. But it obviously broke the old apps with the Google+ sign-in on Android. So I either update to the new system and provide both options on the server side, or just fallback to the old one. Is there any other option that I haven't taken into consideration? Also, I searched everywhere for the API docs of the above server side code, but couldn't find any reference. Could you please point me to the docs? I'll say it again... the documentation is a complete and utter mess...

Comment: Yep, I've filed a bug to get this code included as part of the documentation.

Comment: Cool. So, to sum it up, what are the main differences between using Google+ sign-in vs this new google identity sign-in or whatever it's called? Why use one over the other? Is the old Google+ one going to be deprecated soon?

Comment: @Andrew - the Google profile information is available for all Google users, while Google+ information requires, as you may expect, the user to have created a Google+ profile. Therefore the new sign in is more universal (users won't be asked to create a Google+ profile as was required for Google+ sign in), but you'll only get the basic information rather than the more extensive Google+ data.

Comment: Ok, and last question. If you'd like to call the Google+ API from the server side with the IdToken or serverAuthCode from the auth library on Android, how would that work? Could you point to the associated API docs, if any? I just wanna wrap my head around the whole system, because it's such a mess in its current form (not trying to be an ass, it's just how it is)...